# How to pass column name as parameter in a Stored Procedure in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I want to pass something like `p.lastname` or `p.first_name` in the `query_type` parameter so that i can order by what i want; and accordingly, `query_value` would contain something like `UPPER('%Smith%')` or `UPPER('%Henry%')` depending on what i put in `query_type`.

But when I pass these as strings, the cursor is returned empty.

Any tips? I would ideally not want to get rid of the cursor.

ps. `search_cursor` has been declared as a REF CURSOR in package header.

```
PROCEDURE test_proc(
          company_id IN NUMBER,
          query_type IN VARCHAR2,
          query_value IN VARCHAR2,
          result_limit IN NUMBER,
          cur OUT search_cursor) AS
BEGIN

OPEN cur FOR
select *
from (SELECT p.first_name as "first_name",
             p.surname as "surname",
             row_number()
      OVER (ORDER BY query_type asc) rn
      FROM person p, company c
      WHERE c.employee_id = p.person_id
            AND c.id = company_id
            AND query_type LIKE query_value
      )

where rn BETWEEN 1 AND result_limit;

END test_proc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL. Beware of SQL injection.

As I don't have your tables, I used Scott's sample schema.

Function that returns ref cursor (that's what you do as well, only as procedure's OUT parameter):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    (query_type  in varchar2,
  3     query_value in varchar2
  4    )
  5    return sys_refcursor
  6  is
  7    l_str varchar2(500);
  8    rc    sys_refcursor;
  9  begin
 10    l_str := 'select e.ename, e.job, ' ||
 11             '  row_number() over (order by ' || query_type || ' asc) rn ' ||
 12             'from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno ' ||
 13             'where ' || query_type || ' like ' || query_value;
 14    open rc for l_str;
 15    return rc;
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test('e.ename', q'[upper('%King%')]') from dual;

F_TEST('E.ENAME',Q'[
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME      JOB               RN
---------- --------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT          1


SQL>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! i'm trying to see how you executed the function - what does `dual` signify in your query? Is it a package or a table?

Comment: You're welcome. DUAL is probably the most known **table** in the whole Oracle world. In order to fetch from a function in SQL, you have to SELECT function's value FROM some table; DUAL is a good choice as it contains only 1 row. If you selected from a table with e.g. million rows, you'd get a *million* duplicate results.

Comment: thanks very much. I was able to get the stored procedure to run, but without using a varchar2 variable `l_str`. I just opened cursor 

`OPEN cur FOR 

'select * from (SELECT p.first_name as "first_name", p.surname as "surname", row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ' || query_type || ' asc) rn FROM person p, company c WHERE c.employee_id = p.person_id AND c.id = company_id AND ' || query_type || ' LIKE ' || query_value || ') where rn BETWEEN 1 AND ' || result_limit;`

Comment: You're welcome. I prefer storing the SELECT statement into a variable so that I could **display** it on the screen(using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE) because - if it is complex and knowing that dynamic SQL is difficult to debug - it is useful to actually *see* what you're trying to run. If you put it right away into EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, it might - or might not - work (and then you'll still have to debug it and do what I already did - store the statement into a variable and display it.